# Huge fps drops when using physics2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this for the past couple of days.
Basically the fps drops incredibly on an increased Timescale, the higher the scale the lower the fps. It also depends on how many bullets are being used, the more bullets player/turret shoots the lower the fps as well.

---

**Bullet Movement Script**

```
rb.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, oldTargetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
if (transform.position == oldTargetPosition) { gameObject.SetActive(false); }
```

---

I have also tried `rb.position += dir * speed * Time.deltaTime;` but there seems to be no difference.

`rb.MovePosition()` also had no difference.

---

I'm using OnTriggerEnter2D to detect hits

---

I use the exact same function to move enemies and a pooler for both bullets and enemies

Profiler screenshot1: https://gyazo.com/9f13b5ed1deaec1eb5a331ff75a839e0

Profiler screenshot2: https://gyazo.com/b0be11a871e2897fe89f50009406f7f9

---

I did try and comment out everything else in the FixedUpdate and there is no difference. I would really appreciate any tips/help with this. I'm sure I should be able to shoot tons of bullets without fps drops. While turrets are not shooting and enemies are not spawning even at high timescale (x16) the fps is stable at about 270. As soon as they start shooting it drops to about 90-120, even if its just 1 turret.

Comment: If you have a lot of bullets to deal with, you may want to look into implementing your bullets using DOTS. There is a fantastic demo on how to do this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbnVELXf5RQ). Actual implementation starts after the 3 minute mark.

Comment: It looks great but can I actually use it as of now? On website it says its in preview. Also I am not spawning nearly as many bullets, the other thing is I have increased timescale and that lower the fps a lot, on 1x timescale the fps drops but its still very high.

Comment: I assume you're using colliders on them? And each bullet is checking whether it's collided with something? It would make sense to have it drop significantly when those start spawning and it needs to start looping through the other objects to figure out whether its collided with them. Still though, would need to talk to someone far more familiar with the inner workings of the system to determine exact cause of the dip. Sorry I can't determine more than that with my current knowledge.

Comment: Each bullet has a Trigger collider and uses OnTriggerEnter2D to detect. Do you know of some other way of doing this? Apparently ECS does not really work with WebGL either.

Comment: Are you instantiating gameobjects in your bullet fixedupdate? There seems to be much in that method that you aren't sharing in the question.

Comment: I've mentioned that I use Pooling for everything and there's nothing in the FixedUpdate either. I have also mentioned that I commented out everything in FixedUpdate except rb.position line with no effect.